# Returning default color for items not in domain, using d3.js scale ordinal

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, leaflet

Is there a way to set scaleOrdinal to return a default color if an item doesn't exist in the domain?

For example:

```
var type = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(['WeWork', 'Regus', 'Spaces', 'Knotel', 'RocketSpace', 'HQ Global Workspaces'])
        .range(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'pink']);
```

For all companies that aren't one of the 6 in the domain, I want them to be colored gray.  Is there an easy way to do so without a bunch of extra code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scaleOrdinal.unknown`:

```
var type = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(['WeWork', 'Regus',...])
        .range(['red', 'blue',...])
        .unknown("grey");
```

This assigns a value to unknown inputs:

> ## ordinal.unknown([value]) <>
>
> If value is specified, sets the output value of the scale for unknown
>   input values and returns this scale. If value is not specified,
>   returns the current unknown value, which defaults to implicit. The
>   implicit value enables implicit domain construction; see
>   ordinal.domain. ([from the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#ordinal_unknown))

And here's it at work:

```js
var type = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(['WeWork', 'Regus'])
        .range(['red', 'blue'])
        .unknown("grey");
        
        
var data =  ['WeWork', 'Regus', 'Spaces', 'Knotel', 'RocketSpace', 'HQ Global Workspaces'];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg");
  
svg.selectAll("rect")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i * 40 + 50; })
 .attr("y", 40)
 .attr("width", 30)
 .attr("height", 30)
 .attr("fill", type);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```